# creating dashboard using pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

Using excel trying to filter data using pandas

Using 3 columns name , priority , created date of tickets by implementing groupby functionality

df.groupby("NAME","Createddtm",sort=false)["priority"].count()

getting value error
if level is none and by is none
raise TypeError(you have to supply one of 'by' and 'level')
axis=self._get_axis_number(axis)
return groupby(self,by=by,axis=axis)

valueerror : no axis named create_date for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.Dataframe'>

Answer (score 1):

Pandas groupy expects the column names as a list so your statement should be:
`df.groupby(["NAME","Createddtm"], sort=false)["priority"].count()`